# Checkbox input in python urllib

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib2, urllib

How can I check checkbox if HTML code looks like:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="tos_understood" style="background:none; border:none" />
```

So, my python code is:

```
import urllib
import urllib2
import cookielib

authentication_url = 'http://test.com'

# Input parameters we are going to send
payload = {
  'user': 'newuser',
  'pass': '12345'
  'tos_understood': ??????????
  }

# Use urllib to encode the payload
data = urllib.urlencode(payload)

# Build our Request object
req = urllib2.Request(authentication_url, data)
print req

# Make the request and read the response
resp = urllib2.urlopen(req)
contents = resp.read()
print contents
```

What should I write in tos_understood section? There is no way to login without checked checkbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
payload = {
  'user': 'newuser',
  'pass': '12345',
  'tos_understood': 'on',
  }
```

Comment: Works perfect. `'tos_understood': 'on'` is what I need.

Answer (score 2):

did you try something like :

```
"tos_understood": "1"

 "tos_understood": "checked"
```

or

```
"tos_understood": "on"
```

I looked around for an answer to this but couldnt really find much

If those dont work maybe try something like selenium that actually drives a browser with a window it is waaaayyy easier and you can also run it headless so that the window doesn't pop up